# How to write the related functions for this GHC type families example?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families

At the [GHC/Type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families) web page, it has half a starter example of why type families are useful.

```
data family XList a
data instance XList Char = XCons !Char !(XList Char) | XNil
data instance XList () = XListUnit !Int
```

Basically, it says that a list of `Char` can be represented by cons cells. A list of `()` carries no useful information except its length, so we can represent the list by its length.

That's great. So what about the rest of the implementation of this list. How would `length` be defined, and how would `!!` or `fromList` be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `XList Char` it could be:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
import Prelude hiding ((!!), length)
import qualified Prelude

class XList' a where
    data family XList a :: *
    fromList :: [a] -> XList a
    length   :: XList a -> Int
    (!!)     :: XList a -> Int -> a

instance XList' Char where
    data XList Char = XCons !Char !(XList Char) | XNil

    fromList []     = XNil
    fromList (x:xs) = XCons x (fromList xs)

    length XNil         = 0
    length (XCons x xs) = 1 + length xs

    XNil         !! _ = error "index error!"
    (XCons x xs) !! 0 = x
    (XCons x xs) !! k = xs !! (k - 1)
```

then:

```
\> let a = fromList "wxyz"
\> :t a
a :: XList Char
\> length a
4
\> a !! 2
'y'
```

similarly for `XList ()`:

```
instance XList' () where
    data XList () = XListUnit !Int

    fromList a = XListUnit $ Prelude.length a
    length (XListUnit n) = n

    (XListUnit n) !! k
        | k < 0 || n <= k = error "index error!"
        | otherwise       = ()
```

Comment: Thanks. The web page started with a standalone version instead of being associated with a type class. Can you illustrate how the standalone version would be defined also?

Comment: "Associated" type and data families differ very little. They are not really "associated" in any way other than the compiler will give you warning if you implement the class and not the family (also you can have defaults for associated type and data families). If you move `XList` out of the class, the only difference here is syntactic: `data XList .. where ...` becomes `data instance XList ... where ...` and it is moved outside of the instance declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small addendum:

You can keep `XList a` as a non-typeclass-associated type family and just add a typeclass for the `XList`-y types that hold the operations; e.g.:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

-- Original definition from your question
data family XList a
data instance XList Char = XCons !Char !(XList Char) | XNil
data instance XList () = XListUnit !Int

-- New class for XList-y types
class XListy a where
    length :: XList a -> Int
    (!!) :: XList a -> Int -> a
    fromList :: [a] -> XList a

instance XListy () where
    length (XListUnit n) = n
    _ !! _ = ()
    fromList xs = XListUnit $ Prelude.length xs
```